# Groupby quantile_transform

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas table, with one column the stock ticker, another the date, and I want to, for each date, rescale the returns to follow the uniform distribution. Now, `sklearn.preprocessing` has a perfectly fine `quantile_transform` function for this, but I can't seem to shoehorn it into the pandas `tranform` or `apply` functionality,

The obligatory example:

```
date        ticker volume percent_change
2018-01-01  A       10000     0.01
2018-01-01  AA      15000     0.002
2018-01-01  AAPL    20000     -0.01
2018-01-01  FB      10000     0.05
2018-01-02  A       10000     -0.01
2018-01-02  AA      15000     0.03
2018-01-02  AAPL    20000     -0.02
2018-01-02  FB      10000     -0.01
```

If I wanted to normalize the daily returns to a zscore, the following works fine:

```
zscore = lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std()
df['zscore'] = tsdf.groupby('date')['percent_change'].transform(zscore)
```

but `quantile_transform` seems to be more recalcitrant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
In [216]: for n,g in df.groupby('date'):
     ...:     df.loc[df['date']==n, 'zscore'] = \
                  quantile_transform(df.loc[df['date']==n, ['percent_change']]).ravel()


In [217]: df
Out[217]:
        date ticker  volume  percent_change        zscore
0 2018-01-01      A   10000           0.010  6.666667e-01
1 2018-01-01     AA   15000           0.002  3.333333e-01
2 2018-01-01   AAPL   20000          -0.010  1.000000e-07
3 2018-01-01     FB   10000           0.050  9.999999e-01
4 2018-01-02      A   10000          -0.010  5.005005e-01
5 2018-01-02     AA   15000           0.030  9.999999e-01
6 2018-01-02   AAPL   20000          -0.020  1.000000e-07
7 2018-01-02     FB   10000          -0.010  5.235235e-01
```

[`quantile_transform()`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.quantile_transform.html) expects 2D array as an input - that's why we need square brackets:

```
df.loc[df['date']==n, ['percent_change']]
#                     ^                ^
```

and it returns a 2D matrix as a result, so we would need to flatten (`.ravel()`) it...

Comment: Cool, and might explain why I had been struggling - this is more complicated than I would have expected :)

Comment: @Parfait, thank you for your comment! I've added a short explanation

Comment: Thanks! I actually did not realize that elements of groupby objects were tuples (indexval, dataval). One lives and learns.

Comment: Yes, of course, but I will wait a little to see if someone else has an alternative solution (there is never a single way to do anything. In `pandas`, anyhow).

Answer (score 1):

loop is slow, I have a better way:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import QuantileTransformer
qt = QuantileTransformer(n_quantiles=100, random_state=0)
lam = lambda x: qt.fit_transform(x.values.reshape(-1, 1)).ravel()
df['result'] = df.groupby('date')['percent_change'].transform(lam)
```