# A follow-up to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49239919/pandas-groupby-quantile-transform

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I noticed that `sklearn` does the wrong thing with NaNs: namely, it chokes.
(there is a big discussion of fixing this here:
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/10404)
I would like to transform the non-NaN data and leaves the NaNs alone, in input like:

```
date        ticker volume percent_change
2018-01-01  A       10000     0.01
2018-01-01  AA      15000     0.002
2018-01-01  AAPL    20000     NaN
2018-01-01  FB      10000     0.05
2018-01-02  A       10000     -0.01
2018-01-02  AA      15000     0.03
2018-01-02  AAPL    20000     -0.02
2018-01-02  FB      10000     -0.01
```

(maybe AAPL did not trade that day).

Other than holding my breath for the sklearn guys to fix this, or implementing my own transformer (if done in python, this will be horribly slow, if done in C, painful to integrate), is there some other way of doing this?

Comment: What do you actually want to do with this?

Comment: There are many strategies for dealing with NaNs in machine learning, you just need to decide which one is appropriate for you. This is part of feature engineering and is where data scientists have to earn their money. What does `percent_change` mean in this context? Daily fluctuation? If no trading, then there is no fluctuation, so just set to 0. Or maybe remove the row completely? Try both and see what effects there are in your model.

Comment: @Stev Thanks for the condescending comments. I know exactly what I want to do, my only question was about how to find the implementation of what I need. It turns out, it has been asked before. Your "set to 0" suggestion misses the point completely.

Comment: Not condescending at all and it's disappointing that a professor takes such an attitude. You asked a vague question (which you still haven't explained) and I started by trying to help you with the basics.

Comment: @IgorRivin While you know exactly what you want to do, nobody else does as you haven't explained what you are trying to do in your question!